# Mac Mini (Intel)'s disk has very large read/write

Tags: mac, hard-drive, ssd, mac-mini

I bought a Mac Mini (Intel CPU) about two years ago, and its disk "percentage used" is already 12%, and there are 160TB write (and 150TB read). Compared with other programmers, seems that mine is a little bit too much - many are only one third / half / even smaller compared with mine.

Therefore, I wonder:

1. Is this normal or abnormal?
2. What should I do to improve the situation?

More information (not sure whether this is related):

- CPU is intel i7
- Memory is 32GB
- Usually see a `swap` of 8G~32G
- The only usage is to do programming, no games, video-cutting, etc

Smartctl info:

```
smartctl -a disk0
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [Darwin 20.6.0 x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       APPLE SSD AP0512M
Serial Number:                      C07016500EBJRV2AC
Firmware Version:                   1274.80.
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x106b
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x000000
Controller ID:                      0
NVMe Version:                       <1.2
Number of Namespaces:               1
Local Time is:                      Fri Mar 18 13:29:46 2022 CST
Firmware Updates (0x02):            1 Slot
Optional Admin Commands (0x0004):   Frmw_DL
Optional NVM Commands (0x0004):     DS_Mngmt
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         256 Pages

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     0.00W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        56 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          99%
Percentage Used:                    12%
Data Units Read:                    294,059,879 [150 TB]
Data Units Written:                 313,120,408 [160 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 2,841,131,534
Host Write Commands:                2,066,894,996
Controller Busy Time:               0
Power Cycles:                       154
Power On Hours:                     2,209
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   49
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      0

Read 1 entries from Error Information Log failed: GetLogPage failed: system=0x38, sub=0x0, code=745
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I guess the question to ask you is: does that seem like a reasonable amount of data for your usage? If you're seeing a "usual" level of swap between 8Gb and 32 Gb, then that's quite a high level, which suggests you're using large amounts of data, which is not only getting swapped, but also saved.

Comment: Even so, at 6% per year, it will last you 16 years.

Comment: @nohillside Is this normal or abnormal? What should I do to improve the situation? Thanks

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks for the reply! But interestingly, the "memory pressure" is usually low (average 25%). So what should I do to improve the situation? I am already having a 32GB memory.

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks! So, am I guaranteed if it is not dropped to 0% I am safe? IMHO if I used a lot, it may be less reliable and it has possibly of data loss or even the whole mac mini become garbage and have to pay very high price to fix it since apple fixing is usually expensive :(

Comment: TBH,  just use the Mini as you need. Make sure you have a backup, obviously. Maybe it will last until you buy a new one; maybe it won't.

Comment: @benwiggy Thanks for the reply. But I hope I can make it last longer, if possible :)